# iOS Document Reviewer like Image browser

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, qlpreviewcontroller

I know you can use QLPreviewController to preview a document, but has anyone got a tidy solution to enable gestures (swipes right:left) and preserve the document zoom / navigation.

It has been suggested that we could use a horizontal tableview but initial implementation suggested similar navigation issues.

Any thoughts or suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at FastPDFKit - https://github.com/mobfarm/FastPdfKit

Comment: Hi Nate, thanks for the suggestion, at this point we are trying to present the documents as are, with out conversion to PDF. This might be an option we look to in the future.

Answer (score 0):

[UIPageViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html)?
Sounds like a good fit.